# Spring boot REST application integrating FF4j. How to fix mvc mapping for dependent library?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request-mapping, ff4j

Integrating `FF4j` in my application I've got a queue of issues. Its integrated finally following [recommendation](https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j/issues/308#issuecomment-471561734).
Short description of recommendation is:

- Remove auto-configuration of thymeleaf;
- Add the old thymeleaf version 2.1.4.RELEASE which is used by ff4j-web
- Write a configuration class like FF4JWebConfiguration:

  ```
  @Configuration
  @ConditionalOnClass({ConsoleServlet.class, FF4jDispatcherServlet.class})
  @AutoConfigureAfter(FF4JConfiguration.class)
  public class FF4JWebConfiguration extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(ConsoleServlet ff4jConsoleServlet) {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(ff4jConsoleServlet, "/ff4j-console");
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  public ConsoleServlet getFF4jServlet(FF4j ff4j) {
    ConsoleServlet ff4jConsoleServlet = new ConsoleServlet();
    ff4jConsoleServlet.setFf4j(ff4j);
    return ff4jConsoleServlet;
  }

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean ff4jDispatcherServletRegistrationBean(FF4jDispatcherServlet ff4jDispatcherServlet) {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(ff4jDispatcherServlet, "/ff4j-web-console/*");
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  public FF4jDispatcherServlet getFF4jDispatcherServlet(FF4j ff4j) {
    FF4jDispatcherServlet ff4jConsoleServlet = new FF4jDispatcherServlet();
    ff4jConsoleServlet.setFf4j(ff4j);
    return ff4jConsoleServlet;
  }
  ```

  }

Missed detail in recommendation is maven exclusion:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But it isn't work

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 
14:11:33.605 ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication - Application run failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
```

until I've added some maven exclusion tricks

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

my application successfully launched with corrupted view because of some data doesn't load on ui:

```
13:38:14.785 INFO  o.f.w.FF4jServlet -   __  __ _  _   _
13:38:14.785 INFO  o.f.w.FF4jServlet -  / _|/ _| || | (_)
13:38:14.785 INFO  o.f.w.FF4jServlet - | |_| |_| || |_| |
13:38:14.785 INFO  o.f.w.FF4jServlet - |  _|  _|__   _| |
13:38:14.785 INFO  o.f.w.FF4jServlet - |_| |_|    |_|_/ |
13:38:14.786 INFO  o.f.w.FF4jServlet -              |__/  v1.8
13:38:14.786 INFO  o.f.w.FF4jServlet -
13:38:14.832 INFO  o.f.w.FF4jServlet - Thymeleaf has been initialized
13:38:14.887 INFO  o.t.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF] INITIALIZING TEMPLATE ENGINE
                  13:38:14.971 INFO  o.t.t.AbstractTemplateResolver - [THYMELEAF] INITIALIZING TEMPLATE RESOLVER: org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver
13:38:14.972 INFO  o.t.t.AbstractTemplateResolver - [THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE RESOLVER INITIALIZED OK
                  13:38:14.980 INFO  o.t.T.CONFIG - [THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE CONFIGURATION:
[THYMELEAF] * Cache Factory implementation: org.thymeleaf.cache.StandardCacheManager
[THYMELEAF] * Template modes:
[THYMELEAF]     * VALIDXML
[THYMELEAF]     * XHTML
[THYMELEAF]     * LEGACYHTML5
[THYMELEAF]     * XML
[THYMELEAF]     * VALIDXHTML
[THYMELEAF]     * HTML5
[THYMELEAF] * Template resolvers (in order):
[THYMELEAF]     * org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver
[THYMELEAF] * Message resolvers (in order):
[THYMELEAF]     * [0] customMessageResolver
[THYMELEAF] * Dialect: org.thymeleaf.standard.StandardDialect
[THYMELEAF]     * Prefix: "th"
[THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE CONFIGURED OK
13:38:14.981 INFO  o.t.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE INITIALIZED
13:38:15.648 INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
13:38:15.649 INFO  o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
13:38:15.713 INFO  o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 64 ms
13:38:15.746 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/css/font-awesome-3.2.1.css
13:38:15.747 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css
13:38:15.747 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js
13:38:15.749 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/css/dashboard.css
13:38:15.749 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/css/style.css
13:38:15.750 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css
13:38:15.972 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/js/base.js
13:38:15.973 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/js/bootstrap.js
13:38:15.981 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/img/ff4j.png
13:38:15.989 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/img/flags/flagEnglish.png
13:38:15.989 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/js/ff4j.js
13:38:16.016 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/img/flags/flagMexico.png
13:38:16.030 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/img/flags/flagFrance.png
13:38:16.031 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/img/flags/flagGermany.png
13:38:16.032 WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /static/img/flags/flagJapanese.png 
...
```

it can be fixed with

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
```

But ff4j servlets don't work in my application any way:

```
WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /features
```

### Question

I've detected that `FF4jServlet` initialized and registered all required controllers but I'm not clear why it doesn't work...
Is any ideas how to fix it?

### Some project details:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<ff4j.version>1.8.0</ff4j.version>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to look at

https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j-spring-boot-starter-parent/tree/master/ff4j-spring-boot-sample ?

There are two consoles. Which one are you trying to access ?

Comment: it seems works. But I have no chance to integrate this solution because of snapshot version. How long will it take to release provided solution?

Comment: I tested it with the version 1.8 and it works fine. You can also try it by replacing in the ff4-spring-boot-sample pom.xml the version from snapshot to 1.8 (latest release).

Comment: 1.8 version almost works for me also. The issue with `http://localhost:5000/ff4j-web-console` navigation and controllers. so i can-t use it until it is fixed or 1.9 released.

Comment: Use the following url `http://localhost:5000/ff4j-web-console/` end it with a back slash `/` which is missing.

Comment: it was checked.

Comment: There is neither answer about release nor release. Is it possible to get information about release date? Missed release is `compile group: 'org.ff4j', name: 'ff4j-spring-boot-starter', version: '1.9'`. I voted your answer because it gives me chance to use library without workarounds. But without release it useless, you know.

Comment: Release is planned on 11-May-2019

Comment: I have tested it without any release and it seems to be working fine. You can checkout the project at https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j-spring-boot-starter-parent/blob/sample/1.8/ff4j-spring-boot-sample/pom.xml. You can also check the same version deployed at https://ff4j-sample.herokuapp.com/ff4j-web-console/